# How to generate a dataset like this using mongoDB?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am using mongoDB, nodejs, and mongoose for all DB interactions. I have a DB of orders each with a date and total. I am having trouble creating a small algo to query the orders DB based on date, gather all orders for that date and sum up the totals, then move on to the next date to gather the totals. I want to use the dataset in a [react-charts](https://react-chartjs-2.js.org/) graph. This appears to be a challenge for me.

I want the end result to be two arrays: one with the dates, one with the totals.

Here is what I got

```
    for (var x = 0; x < orders.length; x++) {
      numOfOrders += 1;
      let orderDate = moment(orders[0].placedOn).format('YYYYMMDD');
      // for (var y = 0; y < orders.length; y++) {
      //   // if (moment(orders[y].placedOn).format('YYYYMMDD') === orderDate)
      //   //   // console.log(orders[y].placedOn);

      // }
      // dataSet.push({
      //   total: orders[x].total,
      //   orderedOn: moment(orders[x].placedOn).format('LL'),
      // });
      dataSet.push(orders[x].total);
    }
```